# ¿Cómo puedo sumar coordenadas para calcular distancia en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, indices

Tengo que sumar distancias entre dos puntos. Por el costo, lo voy hacer con una función. El detalle que tengo es que requiero sumar la **coordenada inicial** por la **coordenada destino**, pero a su vez, que después, la coordenada de la respuesta destino para la siguiente coordenada sea la coordenada inicial en JavaScript de forma dinámica (tomando en cuenta que el Array puede tener `n` número de elementos).

```js
var cor = [
  "18.514059,-92.878449",
  "19.614059,-93.688621",
  "18.712578,-94.878728",
  "19.512784,-95.978314",
  "19.679365,-96.876816"
];

function CalcularDistancia(cor) {
  var cordenadas;
  var distancia;
  var posicion1;
  var posicion2;
  var num = 0;
  var parada = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < cor.length; i++) {
    cordenadas = cor[i].split(",");
    if (num > 1) {
      num = 0;
      parada = 3;
      //break;
    }

    if (num == 0) {
      if (parada == 3) {
        posicion1 = posicion1;
      } else {
        posicion1 = cordenadas[0] + "," + cordenadas[1];
      }
    }
    if (num == 1) {
      posicion2 = cordenadas[0] + "," + cordenadas[1];
    }
    num++;

    if (!posicion2 == "") {
      posicion1 = posicion2;
    }
  } //cierre de for
}

CalcularDistancia(cor);
```

---

Ejemplos:

**Primera vuelta**

```js
origen = (lat1, lon1); 
destino = (lat2, lon2);
```

**Segunda vuelta**

```js
origen = (lat2, lon2); 
destino = (lat3, lon3);
```

Que el destino 2 de la primera vuelta se convierta en el origen principal de la vuelta que sigue.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres realmente es sumar las distancias de ese array, creo que es más sencillo utilizar la función `reduce`, que sumará todos los elementos y los irá acumulando ([más información aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)). Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando ES6:

```js
// Datos originales
const coords = [
  "18.514059,-92.878449",
  "19.614059,-93.688621",
  "18.712578,-94.878728",
  "19.512784,-95.978314",
  "19.679365,-96.876816"
];

// Sumar todas las coordenadas aplicando reduce
const result = coords.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const [currentX, currentY] = current.split(',');
  return {
    x: acc.x + Number(currentX),
    y: acc.y + Number(currentY)
  };
}, { x: 0, y: 0 });

// Mostrar resultados
console.log('Resultado suma: ', result);
console.log('Resultado formateado: ', `"${result.x},${result.y}"`);
```

Es posible, por la precisión de los decimales, que alguna suma te dé resultados como "19.12312300000001"; sólo sería necesario redondear, pero esa cuestión ya quedaría fuera de tu pregunta.

Espero que te sirva, puedes utilizar los comentarios si tienes dudas.